# is it possible to allow others to power on/off my nitrous.io box?

Tags: nitrousio

I have a nitrous.io rails box which I and others on my team are using to develop an open-source, not-for-profit app.  Occasionally the box gets auto-powered-off, which is fine, but I want to allow others on the team to be able to power it back on in these cases so they can access it and do work.  Is there a way to do that?  Something like group power on/off/terminal access?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The boxes will shutdown after a certain period of inactivity, unless you have a [paid account](https://www.nitrous.io/pricing). Collaborators will not be able to start a box which does not belong to them, so the only option at this time is share a box which is always on with a subscription plan.